# Adding jump to page link in Bootstrap 3 pagination and styling issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I am using bootstrap 3 pagination. No problems there. Now the client wants a jump-to-page feature to the left of the pagination (see the below mockup image and html to make it look that way). It's giving me fits when I add the jump-to to get it to place properly. I've tried an overall **div** with **position:relative** and the jump-to and pagination within with a **position:absolute**. I've tried a **div** with just jump-to and different positioning. The closest I got was to add the jump-to feature to the **li** of the pagination. This only works with the **a** tag or else it will move to the right of the pagination. (sorry, not very used to the formatting here)

For some reason I can't get it to style properly (remove hover, etc), and place to the left of the pagination, if I remove the **a** tag.

This is totally aggravating me as I know I'm missing something.

I did a search and read a bunch of items with no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the mockup and html. I used inline styles only for quick viewing.

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK6jQ.jpg)

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-right">
  <li class="form-group input-group-sm"><a style="border:none;margin-top:-10px;">Go to page <input size="4" placeholder="page #"></input><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs>Go</button></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: <input size="4" placeholder="page #"></input><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs>Go</button></a></li>↩
  <li><a href="#"><<</a>  you have extra <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few bugs, btw. But that aside, don't put the form group into the same `<ul>` of the pagination since there's lots of styling issues. I think it would be easier to use the go to part `input-group` in a div as it's meant to be, outside the pagination.

http://www.bootply.com/8RxnexxEtD

Remove margins and set display to inline and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. I think I tried everything but that... obviously. :) One more thing. I tried to move the inline styles to their own part my style sheet but it seems to lose the formatting. Do you have a suggestion, my mind is mush? What bugs? What am i missing?

Comment: hard to say without seeing your style sheet and full html. But the html you posted above has border:non instead of none, it has brackets << instead of proper symbol &laquo;

Comment: Whoops. Typing too fast as i'm not allowed to copy/paste into here. It was easy to add to my stylesheet the pagination inline, but it's the one for the jump-to that i'm having issues with. Should I make a specific class for that one? Thanks again.

Comment: A specific class or ID is usually best. Try that! If this answer helped, can you mark that please? THanks!

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Sometimes it's the easy things that you don't see, especially in a rush.